# Is it possible to limit the number of iterations that Criterion performs?

Tags: rust, rust-criterion

I am developing some benchmarks for a crate using criterion (`cargo bench`). I would like to temporarily limit the amount of iterations until I finish the code.

I know measurements may not be precise, but this is just temporary. Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible.

Look at the [Criterion Benchmark](https://docs.rs/criterion/0.2.10/criterion/struct.Benchmark.html). There you can find methods relevant to you, specifically `measurement_time` .

Digging deeper, you can find how to use them [here](https://docs.rs/criterion/0.2.7/criterion/struct.Criterion.html#method.bench):

```
fn bench(c: &mut Criterion) {
    // Setup (construct data, allocate memory, etc)
    c.bench(
        "routines",
        Benchmark::new("routine_1", |b| b.iter(|| routine_1()))
            .with_function("routine_2", |b| b.iter(|| routine_2()))
            .measurement_time(Duration::from_millis(1000))
    );
}

criterion_group!(benches, bench);
criterion_main!(benches);
```

Where `measurement_time(Duration::from_millis(1000))` is the droid you're looking for. This effectively dropped the number of iterations for my specific function by 80%.